Why does UISplitViewController extend the safe area from its primary view's navigation bar to its other views?
I have an iOS app that uses UISplitViewController as its root view controller. The "primary" view of the split view controller (the narrower one on the left) is a navigation controller. Oddly, the safe area applied to the "secondary" view (the one taking up most of the screen) includes that of the navigation bar in the primary view.
If I then embed a navigation controller in a custom right-side split view, its navigation bar gets pushed down by that same safe area.
See this screenshot of a test app on iPad:

The "Root View Controller" text on the right is in the navigation bar of the primary view controller. The blue view at the top in the middle is showing the safe area - its top is pinned to the top edge and its bottom is pinned to the top safe area.
The gray region on the right is a child view controller that contains a navigation controller. "Navigation Bar" there is the navigation item's title in the root view controller of that navigation controller.
How do I stop this extra safe area behavior of UISplitViewController?
Update</b: In the view debugger, I see that the split view controller is wrapping the secondary view in a UINavigationController, and it's that navigation bar that's pushing everything down. This is documented in the UISplitViewController docs.
Here's the code for the "secondary" view controller area in this test app:
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let safeAreaView = UIView()
        safeAreaView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(safeAreaView)
        safeAreaView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        safeAreaView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        safeAreaView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        safeAreaView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        safeAreaView.backgroundColor = .blue
        
        let container = NavContainerViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        self.addChild(container)
        self.view.addSubview(container.view)
        container.didMove(toParent: self)
        container.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        container.view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        container.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        container.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        container.view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.33).isActive = true
    }
}

class NavContainerViewController : UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let child = NavChildController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: child)
        self.addChild(nav)
        self.view.addSubview(nav.view)
        nav.didMove(toParent: self)
        nav.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        nav.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        nav.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        nav.view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        nav.view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}

class NavChildController : UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.text = "Top"
        self.view.addSubview(label)
        label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        
        self.navigationItem.title = "Navigation Bar"
    }
}

